# Getting multiple sub-string matches within one array php

Tags: php, regex

I am attempting to find all rows of an array that contain a specific sub-string.

I have an array containing all my product numbers or SKU's.

I have another array containing paths to images which are found within a directory and its many sub-directories.

(This array of image paths is populated using a RecursiveIterator that goes through the directory and adds all the file paths to this array)

Each image name contains the SKU within it, so sku# 123 may have the following images:
123.jpg
123_1.jpg
123_2.jpg
etc. etc.

I want to output all images that are associated with a particular sku.
Here is the code I have started. For some reason I am only getting the desired result for the last sku.

```
$dir = "./images";          // directory with images
$skus = file("./source.csv");   // source file with all skus
$all_images = array();      // array to hold all image paths found in folder

// recursively search through directory save all file paths to array
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir)) as $f) {
 $all_images[] = $f;   
}

// loop through each sku and find its image paths
for($i=0; $i < count($skus); $i++){
    $values = preg_grep("/$skus[$i]/", $all_images);
    echo "----sku: $skus[$i] -----<br /><br />";

    foreach($values as $val)
        echo "Values: $val<br />";  
}
```

My result page looks something like this:

```
----sku: TR450 -----

----sku: TR451 -----

----sku: TR452 -----

----sku: TR453 -----

----sku: TR454 -----

----sku: TR455 -----

----sku: TR456 -----

Values: ./images\brand\make\TR456 - abacus\TR457.jpg
Values: ./images\brand\make\TR457 - abacus\TR457_Diagram.jpg
Values: ./images\brand\make\TR458 - abacus\Thumbs.db
```

I'm not sure why this is only working for the last SKU??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix the issue by finding that $skus all had spaces at the end of them. Not sure how the spaces got in there but that caused the pattern not to be recognized!

```
('sku123 ' != 'sku123')
```

Here is my code:

```
$dir = "./images";              // directory with images
$skus = file("./source.csv");   // source file with all skus
$skus = array_filter(array_map('trim', $skus)); // this is the only new line, 
                                                //it removes white space after the sku
                                                // so the pattern below can actually work.
$all_images = array();      // array to hold all image paths found in folder

// recursively search through directory save all file paths to array
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir)) as $f) {
 $all_images[] = $f;   
}

// loop through each sku and find its image paths
for($i=0; $i < count($skus); $i++){
    $values = preg_grep("/$skus[$i]/", $all_images);
    echo "----sku: $skus[$i] -----<br /><br />";

    foreach($values as $val)
        echo "Values: $val<br />";  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your pattern in a variable and pass the variable to `preg_grep`.

```
$pattern = '/'. $skus[$i] . '/';
$values = preg_grep($pattern, $all_images);
```

Comment: It's not working, i'm getting the same result (only the last item shows the matching rows) thanks Mike.

Comment: @shnozolla is your `$all_images` array showing the way you believe it should be?

Comment: Yes it is, I have done a foreach on both $all_images, and $skus, they both have correct data.